# TestComplete:Can we integrate Automated Windows UI Testing with Azure DevOps using GitHub?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, testcomplete, azure-devops-extensions

I need to integrate the Automated Windows UI Test project with the Azure DevOps pipeline and use TestComplete code from GitHub. Can't able to integrate the TestComplete Automated UI test when using GitHub.
Can we integrate TestComplete Automated UI Test with Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 0):

TestComplete does integrate with both Git and Azure DevOps.

here are some links to the docs [Azure](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/working-with/integration/azure/test-adapter/index.html)
[Git](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/working-with/integration/scc/git/index.html)